# How do I get a list of Oracle Servers available on my network Using C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle

How do I get list all Oracle Servers available on my network Using C#. I need to get server name and IP address. After some searching find that for SqlServer the following code will work.

```
SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
```

Is there any way to do the same with Oracle?

Comment: Not easily.  If you assume that every database has a listener running on the default port (1521) on that server, you could ping port 1521 on each server and see who responds.  If you happen to use AD/ Oracle Names/ OID for name resolution you could potentially get a list of servers from that server.  You can refine the strategy looking at other ports to see if something that looks like an Oracle listener answers or looking at non-default but common ports but that starts to get challenging.

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need Oracle's data provider for .Net.  Oracle hosts some online tutorials and documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28844/toc.htm) to get you started.

Download: [Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) for Windows](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html)

Example code (provided by Oracle):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

class DataSourceEnumSample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string ProviderName = "Oracle.DataAccess.Client";

        DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(ProviderName);

        if (factory.CanCreateDataSourceEnumerator)
        {
            DbDataSourceEnumerator dsenum = factory.CreateDataSourceEnumerator();
            DataTable dt = dsenum.GetDataSources();

            // Print the first column/row entry in the DataTable
            Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[0] + " : " + dt.Rows[0][0]);
            Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[1] + " : " + dt.Rows[0][1]);
            Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[2] + " : " + dt.Rows[0][2]);
            Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[3] + " : " + dt.Rows[0][3]);
            Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[4] + " : " + dt.Rows[0][4]);
        }
        else
            Console.Write("Data source enumeration is not supported by provider");
    }
}
```

The returned datatable contains:

- InstanceName
- ServerName
- ServiceName
- Protocol
- Port

Once you have the server name you can find it's IP via `Dns.GetHostAddresses(string hostname)`.

Comment: But this throwing some error.  "The procedure entry point ons_init_wconfig_ctx could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\oracle\OraOCIEI1.dll"

Comment: Using Oracle 10g and 11g Express Editions and ODP.NET, its available in C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0(for 10g). And I think Oracle server installation include client components.In my application doing following operation such as fetching,saving and OS Level Authentication.And everything working fine except this server finding code.